# Displaying images from file in GridView is very slow on Android

Tags: android, gridview

I have two problems:

1. The delay before displaying images in gridview is very long: 15s!!! And I don't know how to solve this.
2. When images are loaded in gridview and I try to scroll down (or up) to see the rest of images, the mobile phone takes a long time to display them. Moreover, if I scroll very fast the application stops.

Remark: the e var is used to give a different color to the background each jump +1 ( green / blue/ green....)

Thanks in advance, and here the code:

CODE: **res/layout/ main_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



     <GridView
    android:id="@+id/PhoneImageGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE: **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
     int e=0; // To change the background color 
    String[] Files;
    ImageView selection;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get images paths and store them in f
            getFromSdcard();

           GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);

            imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }

    /*GET images paths */
    public void getFromSdcard()
    {

        File file=  new File("mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO");

            if (file.exists())
            {
                Files = file.list();

                for (int i = 0; i < Files.length; i++)
                {
                    f.add(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Files[i]);
              }

            }

    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context ctxt;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

                this.ctxt=c;
                }

        public int getCount() {
            return f.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public void setColorType(){
            if(e==0)
                e= 1;
            else{e= 0;}

        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            ImageView c;

            if (convertView == null) {
                c= new ImageView(ctxt);

                //Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));// Files[position]
                c.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80,80));
                c.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                c.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

                if(e==0){
                     c.setBackgroundColor( -65536);
                     setColorType();
                    }
                else{
                    setColorType();
                    c.setBackgroundColor( -16711936);
                }

            }
            else {
                c= (ImageView) convertView;

                if(e==0){
                     c.setBackgroundColor( 00000);
                     setColorType();
                    }

            }

            Bitmap myBitmap = decodeFile(new File(f.get(position)));
            c.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            return c;
        }


    }



// To solve the issue of uploading image and avoid error ** Out of memory   

    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale*=2;

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;


            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace these lines

```
Bitmap myBitmap = decodeFile(new File(f.get(position)));
c.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

with

```
if(c.getTag() != null) {
    ((ImageGetter) c.getTag()).cancel(true);
}
ImageGetter task = new ImageGetter(c) ;
task.execute(new File(f.get(position)));
c.setTag(task);
```

and create this class `ImageGetter` that gets the image in the background:

```
public class ImageGetter extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView iv;
    public ImageGetter(ImageView v) {
        iv = v;
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(File... params) {
        return decodeFile(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        iv.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this, but it's not working properly, the images are load faster but the problem is you see the imageViews one by one white then the image is display on it and when you scroll down or up the system overwrite the images

Comment: yes of course, the images need time to load and that's is why you see the white before. As for the image replacement, add `c.setImageBitmap(null);` before `ImageGetter task = new ImageGetter(c);`

Comment: Is not working, When I scroll down or up the imageView is initialized to white.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think it would be faster and more scallable if you you do all the load part in thread. In adapter every image would be loaded in thread (and e.g. for the time of load you can display progress bar in gridview cell). After thread finished you just swap grid view cell with image content. Of course user can swipe grid view faster than threads load images therefore you have to attach thread to cell and be sure only one thread works for one cell so they won't swap each other work result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've read this before on the net but I'm new in android I didn't understand well the example. I found them  not well documented and not well explaned as java documentation. But I will take your advice in account and I will try it later. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by below code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
 int e=0; // To change the background color 
String[] Files;
ImageView selection;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get images paths and store them in f
        getFromSdcard();

       GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);

        imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

}

/*GET images paths */
public void getFromSdcard()
{

    File file=  new File("mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO");

        if (file.exists())
        {
            Files = file.list();

            for (int i = 0; i < Files.length; i++)
            {
                f.add(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Files[i]);
          }

        }

}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctxt;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

            this.ctxt=c;
            }

    public int getCount() {
        return f.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public void setColorType(){
        if(e==0)
            e= 1;
        else{e= 0;}

    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ImageView c;

        if (convertView == null) {
            c= new ImageView(ctxt);

            //Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));// Files[position]
            c.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80,80));
            c.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            c.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

            if(e==0){
                 c.setBackgroundColor( -65536);
                 setColorType();
                }
            else{
                setColorType();
                c.setBackgroundColor( -16711936);
            }

        }
        else {
            c= (ImageView) convertView;

            if(e==0){
                 c.setBackgroundColor( 00000);
                 setColorType();
                }

        }

        Bitmap myBitmap = decodeFile(new File(f.get(position)));
        c.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        return c;
    }


}
```

// To solve the issue of uploading image and avoid error ** Out of memory

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = 4;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = 4;


        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

}

```
Just changed  o2.inSampleSize = 4; and  o.inSampleSize = 4;
```

Also change the below code also

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(f.get(position), options);
Bitmap myBitmap2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 100, 100, true);
                                c.setImageBitmap(myBitmap2);
```

by replacing `Bitmap myBitmap = decodeFile(new File(f.get(position)));
        c.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);`

Comment: First Thanks for your reply,okay I will try

Comment: The code works perfectly, but the main problem persists scrolling image is slow.

Comment: use a custom grid view. It will solve your slow scrolling problem